# Do we have any detailed documentation of Firebase for Flutter?

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, documentation

I have started learning flutter and working on a mobile application that uses Firebase as a backend. I found documentation of Firebase for multiple languages and platforms like iOS, Android, Java, C++, Node.js, etc. But I wonder if we have any official documentation for Flutter. Here are the few links I'm following, but they are not proving enough information.

[Flutter Plugins Documentation](https://pub.dev/documentation/cloud_firestore),
[Flutter Documentation](https://flutter.dev/docs)

and StackOverflow and other communities for issues. 
Can anyone please provide links that provide more information about the firebase implementation in flutter apps. Thanks & Regards.

Answer (score 1):

I would like to share with you some of the resources that I found for you to get a fresh start with Firebase for Flutter.

> 1. This first link is a **[tutorial](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/flutter-firebase/#0)** from Codelabs. You'll learn
>      how to create a Flutter app that uses Firebase. The app helps new
>      parents choose baby names by letting friends and family vote for
>      their favorites. Specifically, the app accesses a Cloud Firestore
>      database, and a user action in your app (i.e., tapping a name
>      option) updates the database using a transaction.
> 2. This other link is a to **[Add Firebase to your Flutter app](https://firebase.google.com/docs/flutter/setup?)** guide.
>      You'll learn how to set up your environment and configure your app
>      to use Firebase for your app back-end service.
> 3. Also, this is a good **[reading](https://medium.com/enappd/adding-firebase-to-your-flutter-app-281b8f391b47)**. This could be an additional
>      resource to adding Firebase to your Flutter app to gain a deeper
>      understanding. There are some fantastic graphs and explanations.
> 4. Lastly, this is a step-by-step tutorial to **[Building a chat app
>      with Flutter and Firebase from scratch](https://medium.com/flutter-community/building-a-chat-app-with-flutter-and-firebase-from-scratch-9eaa7f41782e)**. I'm not sure what your use
>      case may be, but this will definetely help you get acquainted with
>      the tools needed to use Firebase for Flutter.

Hope you find it useful.

Answer (score 0):

https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/flutter-firebase/#0

Codelabs has the way you should start!!